# How to generate random values in range (-1, 1) such that the total sum is 0?

Tags: python, random

If the sum is 1, I could just divide the values by their sum. However, this approach is not applicable when the sum is 0.

Maybe I could compute the opposite of each value I sample, so I would always have a pair of numbers, such that their sum is 0. However this approach reduces the "randomness" I would like to have in my random array.

Are there better approaches?

Edit: the array length can vary (from 3 to few hundreds), but it has to be fixed before sampling.

Comment: How much of a zero your zero sum needs to be? And over how many numbers?

Comment: @norok2 The array length can be variable (from 3 to few hundreds). The sum should be at least as close to zero as possible, if the exact sum is not possible.

Comment: You can use a variation of your approach by generating the opposite numbers and then add random noise to those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sklearns Standardscaler. It scales your data to have a variance of 1 and a mean of 0. The mean of 0 is equivalent to a sum of 0.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np
rand_numbers = StandardScaler().fit_transform(np.random.rand(100,1, ))
```

If you don't want to use sklearn you can standardize by hand, the formula is pretty simple:

```
rand_numbers = np.random.rand(1000,1, )
rand_numbers = (rand_numbers - np.mean(rand_numbers)) / np.std(rand_numbers)
```

The problem here is the variance of 1, that causes numbers greater than 1 or smaller than -1. Therefor you devide the array by its max abs value.

```
rand_numbers = rand_numbers*(1/max(abs(rand_numbers)))
```

Now you have an array with values between -1 and 1 with a sum really close to zero.

```
print(sum(rand_numbers))
print(min(rand_numbers))
print(max(rand_numbers))
```

Output:

```
[-1.51822999e-14]
[-0.99356294]
[1.]
```

What you will have with this solution is either one 1 or one -1 in your data allways. If you would want to avoid this you could add a positive random factor to the division through the max abs. `rand_numbers*(1/(max(abs(rand_numbers))+randomfactor))`

**Edit**

As @KarlKnechtel mentioned the division by the standard deviation is redundant with the division by max absolute value.

The above can be simply done by:

```
rand_numbers = np.random.rand(100000,1, )
rand_numbers = rand_numbers - np.mean(rand_numbers)
rand_numbers = rand_numbers / max(abs(rand_numbers))
```

Comment: Thank you! The upper and lower limits are not a strict constraint, so I can definitely use the method you proposed.

Comment: Note that this is not going to be uniformly distributed but will have a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @norok what brings you to that conclusion? I don't see why it will becoma a gaussian distibution. I just did plot a histogram of 1 million random numbers created with the method above and its normally distributed.

Comment: The division by the standard deviation is redundant with the division by max absolute value.

Comment: @FlorianH Actually, you are right. The distribution will be just a scaling of whatever distribution you pass on. My mistake.

Comment: It's not uniformly distributed. For example, for 2 numbers, your approach generates (x1 - x2) / 2 and (x2 - x1) / 2 (let's just ignore scaling) where x1 and x2 are independent random variables that are uniformly distributed on [-1,1]. Unfortunately, the distribution of (x1 - x2) / 2 is an [Irwin–Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), which is not uniform.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Dirichlet-Rescale (DRS) algorithm](https://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/167646/) that generates random numbers summing up to a given number. As it says, it has the feature that

> the vectors are uniformly distributed over the valid region of the
> domain of all possible vectors, bounded by the constraints.

There is also a [Python library](https://pypi.org/project/drs/) for it.

Comment: Nice reference. To answer the specific question, one can use `result = drs(n, 0, [1 for _ in range(n)], [-1 for _ in range(n)])`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following solution:

```
def draw_randoms_while_sum_not_zero(eps):
    r = random.uniform(-1, 1)
    sum = r
    yield r
    while abs(sum) > eps:
        if sum > 0:
            r = random.uniform(-1, 0)
        else:
            r = random.uniform(0,1)
        sum += r
        yield r
```

As the floating point numbers are not perfectly accurate, you can never be sure, that the numbers you'd draw might sum up to 0. You need to decide, what margin is acceptable and call the above generator.

It'll yield (lazily return) random numbers as you need them as long as they don't sum up to `0 ± eps`

```
epss = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001]

for eps in epss:
    lengths = []
    for _ in range(100):
        lengths.append(len(list(draw_randoms_while_sum_not_zero(eps))))
    print(f'{eps}: min={min(lengths)}, max={max(lengths)}, avg={sum(lengths)/len(lengths)}')
```

Results:

```
0.1: min=1, max=24, avg=6.1
0.01: min=1, max=174, avg=49.27
0.001: min=4, max=2837, avg=421.41
0.0001: min=5, max=21830, avg=4486.51
1e-05: min=183, max=226286, avg=48754.42
```

Comment: This would take very long time for small sizes and very low eps, and there is no control over the lenght of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you! That's an interesting approach, but as mentioned in the previous comment, it doesn't take into account the length of the array.

Comment: @phoenix just add counting

Answer (score 0):

One way to generate such list is by having the opposite number.
If that is not a desirable property, you can introduce some extra randomness by adding / subtracting the same random value to different opposite couples, e.g.:

```
def exact_sum_uniform_random(num, min_val=-1.0, max_val=1.0, epsilon=0.1):
    items = [random.uniform(min_val, max_val) for _ in range(num // 2)]
    opposites = [-x for x in items]
    if num % 2 != 0:
        items.append(0.0)
    for i in range(len(items)):
        diff = random.random() * epsilon
        if items[i] + diff <= max_val \
                and any(opposite - diff >= min_val for opposite in opposites):
            items[i] += diff
            modified = False
            while not modified:
                j = random.randint(0, num // 2 - 1)
                if opposites[j] - diff >= min_val:
                    opposites[j] -= diff
                    modified = True
    result = items + opposites
    random.shuffle(result)
    return result


random.seed(0)
x = exact_sum_uniform_random(3)
print(x, sum(x))
# [0.7646391433441265, -0.7686875811622043, 0.004048437818077755] 2.2551405187698492e-17
```

---

## EDIT

If the upper and lower limits are not strict, a simple way to construct a zero sum sequence is to sum-normalize two separate sequences to 1 and -1 and join them together:

```
def norm(items, scale):
    return [item / scale for item in items]


def zero_sum_uniform_random(num, min_val=-1.0, max_val=1.0):
    a = [random.uniform(min_val, max_val) for _ in range(num // 2)]
    a = norm(a, sum(a))
    b = [random.uniform(min_val, max_val) for _ in range(num - len(a))]
    b = norm(b, -sum(b))
    result = a + b
    random.shuffle(result)
    return result


random.seed(0)
n = 3
x = exact_mean_uniform_random(n)
print(exact_mean_uniform_random(n), sum(x))
# [1.0, 2.2578843364303585, -3.2578843364303585] 0.0
```

---

Note that both approaches will not have, in general, a uniform distribution.

Comment: Thank you! But the sum converges to 0 only if I take a large number of samples. If I have only 3 samples for example, I would still have a sum which is quite large.

Comment: @phoenix Uhm, are you referring to `exact_sum_uniform_random()`?

Comment: @phoenix In the example I show it is with 3 samples and the sum is close to 0 (`2.2551405187698492e-17`). But if the upper/lower bounds are not strict, you may be better off with the approach in `zero_sum_uniform_random()`.

Comment: No I was referring to your previous answer. Regarding your current answer, the sum is exact but randomness is more important in my case.

Comment: @phoenix But that is just as random as `random.uniform()` gets...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fine with the approach of generating lots of numbers and dividing by the sum, why not generate n/2 positive numbers divide by sum. Then generate n/2 negative numbers and divide by sum?

Want a random positive to negative mix? Randomly generate that mix randomly first then continue.