# Put constraits on six random numbers making three negative and three positive and equating to 1?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

How do i make three random negative numbers and three positive random numbers equal 1 constrained between -1 and 1. For example,

```
         random_nums = np.array([-.2,-.3,-.5,.5,.8,.7])) = 1
```

I dont want np.uniform answers I need 6 random numbers in arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[4],arr[5],arr[6] =1. Then want to shuffle them in different order shuffle(random_nums).

Comment: Generate 3 random numbers, then add the negative and positive value of each

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate random values in range (-1, 1) such that the total sum is 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407760/how-to-generate-random-values-in-range-1-1-such-that-the-total-sum-is-0)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, numbers generated by this scheme will never be truly "random", since to satisfy this constraint, you will have to, well, constrain some of them.

But, that warning aside, here's one way to generate such arrays:

1. Generate a pair (a,b) where a = rand(), and b=-rand()
2. If a+b < 0, reverse keep (a,b), otherwise a,b = -a, -b
3. Repeat with another pair (c,d)
4. If a+b+c+d < 1  then keep (c,d), otherwise c,d = -c, -d.
5. If a+b+c+d < 0 then a,b,c,d = -a, -b, -c, -d
6. You should now have a positive a+b+c+d. Obtain a random number e in the range [-(a+b+c+d), 0]
7. Your final number is f = 1 - (a+b+c+d+e)

rough (untested) example of python implementation:

```
def getSix():
    a = numpy.random.rand()
    b = -numpy.random.rand()
    a,b = (a,b) if a+b > 0 else (-a,-b)
    c = numpy.random.rand()
    d = -numpy.random.rand()
    c,d = (c,d) if a+b+c+d < 1 else (-c, -d)
    a,b,c,d = (a,b,c,d) if a+b+c+d > 0 else (-a, -b, -c, -d)
    e = -numpy.random.rand()*(a+b+c+d)
    f = 1 - (a+b+c+d+e)
    return numpy.array([a,b,c,d,e,f])
```

Obviously this is very specific to your case of 6 elements, but you could figure out a way to generalise it to more elements if necessary.

Comment: Constraints don't make the set nonrandom, it just means there are fewer degrees of freedom.  Consider our old friend the sample variance s^2 --  since s^2 depends on x-bar, it only has n-1 degrees of freedom because any subset of n-1 values can contain any values but the last observation is determined by the first n-1 and the mean.  Yet you wouldn't argue that s^2 isn't a random variable, would you?

Comment: @pjs agreed. I wanted to say something like that in the answer but stopped short because I wasn't sure how to word it usefully. I suppose what I was warning against is the wording in the question; OP says "a set of 6 random numbers", not "a random set of 6 numbers", given a constraint. It's a pedantic point to make, but, while the latter sounds fine to me (because we're drawing a set at random from a finite range of valid sets) the former sounds as if one expects _all_ numbers to have some guarantee of being drawn truly at random somehow while still satisfying constraints, which is impossible.

Comment: @pjs but I'm glad you made that comment :)

Answer (score 1):

It's may be counter-intuitive, but actually, you can't :

```
1) the last one of them must be non-random so that the sum equals 1.
2) the penultimate must be in an interval such that when summed with
   the first four, the result is between 0 and 2. 
3) the antepenultimate must be in an interval such that when summed with
   the first three, the result is between -1 and 3. and so on...
```

The numbers are constrained, so they can't be random.

What you can do to approach the solution is to use a backtracking algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to your problem. Your problem can be formulated with the following equation:

`x + y + z + p + q + r = 1`, where x, y, z > 0 and p, q, r < 0.

As you can see, this is an indeterminate equation. This means that it has infinite solutions, thus your requirements cannot be met.

Comment: You are using list comprehension wrongly: `result = [-num for num in tmp_list]`.

Comment: This is no solution for the OPs problem.

Comment: An indeterminate equation, far from having no solution, has an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @gboffi The solution, which is to programatically solve OP's problem, is impossible. But I agree that I didn't make it clear that the number of solutions to the equation is infinite, thank you for noticing!

Comment: Btw this is not indeterminate, you forgot the contraint that x,y,z < 1 and p,q,r > -1. With this extra constraint, the solution set is bound to finite ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Not truly random due to the sum constraint and a floating point sum to an exact value can be problematic due to floating point rounding as well, but with a little brute force, the Decimal module and computing the sixth value of five random numbers, the following example works.

The code below generates five random numbers and computes sixth for the sum requirement and loops until 3 of 6 numbers are negative:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import random

def get_nums():
    while True:
        # Use integers representing 100ths to prevent float rounding error.
        nums = [random.randint(-100,100) for _ in range(5)]
        nums.append(100-sum(nums)) # compute 6th number so sum is 100.
        # Check that 6th num is in right range and three are negative.
        if -100 <= nums[5] <= 100 and sum([1 if num < 0 else 0 for num in nums]) == 3:
            break
    return [Decimal(n) / 100 for n in nums]

for _ in range(10):
    print(get_nums())
```

Output:

```
[Decimal('-0.36'), Decimal('0.89'), Decimal('0.39'), Decimal('1'), Decimal('-0.05'), Decimal('-0.87')]
[Decimal('-0.01'), Decimal('0.12'), Decimal('0.98'), Decimal('-0.48'), Decimal('-0.45'), Decimal('0.84')]
[Decimal('0.99'), Decimal('0.5'), Decimal('-0.29'), Decimal('0.49'), Decimal('-0.65'), Decimal('-0.04')]
[Decimal('0.51'), Decimal('-0.03'), Decimal('0.64'), Decimal('-0.96'), Decimal('0.99'), Decimal('-0.15')]
[Decimal('0.51'), Decimal('-0.27'), Decimal('-0.62'), Decimal('0.67'), Decimal('-0.22'), Decimal('0.93')]
[Decimal('-0.25'), Decimal('0.84'), Decimal('-0.23'), Decimal('-0.59'), Decimal('0.94'), Decimal('0.29')]
[Decimal('0.75'), Decimal('-0.39'), Decimal('0.86'), Decimal('-0.81'), Decimal('0.6'), Decimal('-0.01')]
[Decimal('-0.4'), Decimal('-0.46'), Decimal('0.89'), Decimal('0.94'), Decimal('0.27'), Decimal('-0.24')]
[Decimal('-0.87'), Decimal('0.6'), Decimal('0.95'), Decimal('-0.12'), Decimal('0.9'), Decimal('-0.46')]
[Decimal('0.5'), Decimal('-0.58'), Decimal('-0.04'), Decimal('-0.41'), Decimal('0.68'), Decimal('0.85')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach that uses sum-normalization:

```
import numpy as np


def gen_rand(n):
    result = np.array((np.random.random(n // 2) + 1).tolist() + (np.random.random(n - n // 2) - 1).tolist())
    result /= np.sum(result)
    return result


rand_arr = gen_rand(6)
print(rand_arr, np.sum(rand_arr))
# [ 0.70946589  0.62584558  0.77423647 -0.51977241 -0.28432949 -0.30544603] 1.0
```

Basically, we generate N / 2 numbers in the range (1, 2) and N / 2 numbers in the range (0, -1) and then these gets sum-normalized.
The algorithm does not guarantee exact results, but as N increases the probability of invalid results goes to zero.

```
N = 100000
failures = 0
for i in range(N):
    rand_arr = gen_rand(6)
    if np.any(rand_arr > 1) or np.any(rand_arr < -1):
        failures += 1
print(f'Drawings: {N}, Failures: {failures}, Rate: {failures / N:.2%}')
# Drawings: 100000, Failures: 1931, Rate: 1.93%
```

Therefore, you could just combine it with some other logic to just discard invalid generations, if you are strict on the requirements, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np


def gen_rand_strict(n):
    result = np.full(n, 2.0, dtype=float)
    while np.any(result > 1) or np.any(result < -1):
        result = np.array((np.random.random(n // 2) + 1).tolist() + (np.random.random(n - n // 2) - 1).tolist())
        result /= np.sum(result)
    return result

rand_arr = gen_rand_strict(6)
print(rand_arr, np.sum(rand_arr))
# [ 0.55928446  0.5434739   0.38103321 -0.24799626 -0.09556285 -0.14023246] 1.0


N = 100000
failures = 0
for i in range(N):
    rand_arr = gen_rand_strict(6)
    if np.any(rand_arr > 1) or np.any(rand_arr < -1):
        failures += 1
print(f'Drawings: {N}, Failures: {failures}, Rate: {failures / N:.2%}')
# Drawings: 100000, Failures: 0, Rate: 0.00%
```

---

Actually, with the logic to ensure values within the exact range, you do not need to put much thinking into the ranges and this would also work well:

```
import numpy as np


def gen_rand_strict(n):
    result = np.full(n, 2.0, dtype=float)
    while np.any(result > 1) or np.any(result < -1):
        result = np.array((np.random.random(n // 2) * n).tolist() + (np.random.random(n - n // 2) * -n).tolist())
        result /= np.sum(result)
    return result

rand_arr = gen_rand_strict(6)
print(rand_arr, np.sum(rand_arr))
# [ 0.32784034  0.75649476  0.8097567  -0.2923395  -0.41629451 -0.1854578 ] 1.0


N = 100000
failures = 0
for i in range(N):
    rand_arr = gen_rand_strict(6)
    if np.any(rand_arr > 1) or np.any(rand_arr < -1):
        failures += 1
print(f'Drawings: {N}, Failures: {failures}, Rate: {failures / N:.2%}')
# Drawings: 100000, Failures: 0, Rate: 0.00%
```